# Diagnosis: Gasoline leak

Tags: dodge, leak, gasoline

My grandmother has a 2002 Dodge Intrepid ES 3.5L.

Observations:

It is leaking gasoline fumes (not liquid; that I have found) after running the vehicle for some time and for about 30 mins to an hour after stopping.

The smell is strongest just after stopping the car and is definitely strongest near the engine compartment.

This site seems to indicate that it is probably a slow leak from a fuel injector O-ring:
http://www.simple-car-answers.com/Gasoline-Smell-in-Car.html

Am I missing anything and do the symptoms match the theoretical problem?

Comment: Is it hard to start the engine when the engine is hot?

Comment: No, but we have to pump the gas pedal a few times to start it cold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leak was in a fuel line leading to the injector.